# Chrome DevTools for Node.js not loading source maps

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome, devtools

I am working on a node.js API. We use typescript and I use Chrome dev tools for debuging. In the last day when I started the chrome node inspector it could not load my resource maps. I tried making a small mock project and it happened for that one too.

The warning it gives is `DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for file://<path_to_source_map>: No setting registered: network.enable-unc-loading`. I have the latest version of chrome 105 and I am on macOS 12.5.1.

I was thinking it might have something with mac permission but when I take the link to the file `file://<path_to_source_map>` and open it in browser it can open my file and I can add the file trough workspaces but it cannot link them even if I do it manually. I do not know if it is a chrome setting or what.

Any ideas ?

Comment: This is very weird. This issue also appeared for me just this morning, but I use inline source maps encoded as base64. Pasting the base64 code into the search browser search bar correctly decodes it. This seems to be an issue with the 105 release of Chrome as I tested 104 and everything works. I opened an issue here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1360298

Comment: When I click `file://<path_to_source_map>` it is opened as `about:blank` on the chrome by the way

Comment: Anyone know the cause? I'm getting these errors in windows, node, chrome 105.0.5195.102 (Official Build) (64-bit)?  Im getting same thing on my mac.  My co-worker on the otherhand (mac w/ same versions) is not.

Answer (score 2):

I've found this setting:

[image: network.enable-unc-loading]

But this setting is not available in the Dev Tools console for Remote Targets so it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: This setting is present for me in Node.js DevTools in Canary `107.0.5290.1`.

Comment: And while it didn't work at first, eventually that made it work for me.

Comment: also don't have this setting. Been debugging until today and now it seems everyone has the same issue.

Comment: In my case, I have updated chrome and now it works again.

Comment: This issue started happening for me in Brave Version 1.44.105 Chromium: 106.0.5249.91 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I switched to Chrome Version 106.0.5249.91 (Official Build) (64-bit) and the issues does not occur. ‍♂️